# Is it possible to combine two linear regression models (same structure, different data)?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, statistics, regression

Let's say I have `x`, `y`, both are 1d vector and 1000 elements long. If I have trained two linear regression models on two halves of the data separately (e.g., model A for the first half, model B for the second half), is it possible to combine them?

- To be specific, I am fitting a model: `y_i = a x_i + b`, where `a` and `b` are the fitting parameters.
- The two models give `a_1`, `a_2`, `b_1`, and `b_2`.
- Is it possible to express `a` and `b` in terms of above to obtain a full model that is trained on all data?

It seems to be related to online learning as well.

Comment: Would it be easier to compute ```sum(x_i)```, ```sum (y_i)```, and ```sum (x_i*y_i)``` for the first half and second half respectively, and combine the sums to compute ```a``` and ```b```?

Comment: This isn't so much a programming question as a stats theory question, which is not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at stack overflow but probably belongs on stackexchange network site [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining multiple datasets vs combining regression models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235577/combining-multiple-datasets-vs-combining-regression-models)

Comment: @YuxinWang, Thanks for the direction.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, the link's solution was basically combining the data rather than a way to combine the trained models.

Comment: My read of those questions is that the answer to your question is "no" but I could be wrong. You'd get a more informed answer over there. Good luck to you!